# Double expansion of a parameter in Bash script

Tags: bash

I want to expand a parameter twice, and `${$PARAM}` doesn't work.

For example, if I set two variables to file names and then want to loop through those variables and expand to their file names:

```
INPF_1=input1.inp
INPF_2=input2.inp

# copy the input files to the execution directory
for input_param in ${!INPF_*}; do
    echo ${$input_param}
done
```

How can I to access the file names from those parameters in the for loop?

I.e., expand to `input1.inp` and `input2.inp`.

Comment: This would be easier if you used a single array. `infp=( input1.inp input2.inp )`

Comment: What you're trying to do is called indirect expansion, though. We already have questions and answers covering it.

Answer (score 2):

You had it almost: just use `"${!input_param}"` instead of `${$input_param}`.

The quoting doesn't do anything in this case, but it's a good habit.

Be aware of the difference to `${!INPF_@}`, which – when used between double quotes – expands to a separate word for each variable name, whereas `"${!INPF_*}"` doesn't. You almost always want `"${!INPF_@}"`. See the difference:

```
$ for var in  "${!INPF_*}"; do echo "$var"; done
INPF_1 INPF_2
$ for var in  "${!INPF_@}"; do echo "$var"; done
INPF_1
INPF_2
```

See the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) for the various parameter expansions.

Comment: This doesn't get me the file names though. I've updated to make clearer.

Comment: @salotz Ah, I see. Updating.

Comment: I actually go this far, but I didn't realize the * vs @ difference. The duplicate answer gives the rest, or like @Charles Duffy says use an array like a normal programming language.